# How to have the whole object act as optionValue in a SelctInput in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

Consider the following simple example for a `SelectInput` field with static choices in react-admin:

```
<SelectInput source="category" choices={[
    { id: '1', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Photography' },
]} />
```

When the user selects a choice, the category field is filled with the id as expected.
I'd like to have the category field filled with the whole object, like `{ id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' }` instead of just `'2'`. The API I'm using unfortunately requires that.

I tried with

```
const myWeirdChoices = [{ id: { id: '1', name: 'Programming' }, name: 'Programming' },
        { id: { id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' }, name: 'Lifestyle' },
        { id: { id: '3', name: 'Photography' }, name: 'Photography' }];

<SelectInput source="category" choices={myWeirdChoices } />
```

but now the `SelectInput` is empty even if the field already contained a proper value. 
Is there a prop on `SelectInput` which tells the component to use the whole thing as an `OptionValue` instead of just the id, so I can use the more elegant first code block?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this.  the OptionValue argument is only allowed to be a property name of a value field, even if it is a nested one, its value must not be an object.
And beware, if you set this to anything other than 'id' when the ReferenceInput, you will get a dataProvider get call to that, as if it was the id of the resource.  That probably isn't what you want and that behavior is arguably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As of React-Admin v3.13 this is possible using  [`parse` and `format`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#recipes).

```
  const choices = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Programming' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Photography' },
  ];
      
  <SelectInput
    source="category"
    choices={choices}
    format={(c) => c.name}
    parse={(name) => choices.find((c) => c.name === name)}
  />
```

`format` makes sure the form options in the html are just the `name` strings. `parse` translates the selected option into the format you db needs.