# How to pass 2 or more optionValue fields in React Admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-admin

I want to allow the user to choose a teacher's name from a drop down and insert that teacher's "teacher_name" and "teacher_id" as 2 separate fields in Firestore database.

I have the following input field which creates a drop down by "teacher_name". Now I can either pass "teacher_name" OR "teacher_id" under optionValue to insert that field. Is there a way to insert both "teacher_name" AND "teacher_id" as 2 separate fields?

```
<ReferenceInput
  label="Teacher"
  source="teacher_name"
  reference="teachers"
>
  <AutocompleteInput
    optionText="teacher_name"
    optionValue="teacher_name"
    defaultValue={null}
  />
</ReferenceInput>
```

My Firestore looks like this:

Collection name : teachers

Document Structure :

```
{ 
    teacher_id : "XXX",
    teacher_name : "XXX",
    other_fields : "XXX",
}
```

Comment: Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518589/15774176) which explains How to have the whole object act as optionValue in a SelctInput in react-admin as :

> This is possible using [parse and format](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#recipes). Format makes sure the
> form options in the html are just the name strings. parse translates
> the selected option into the format you db needs.
>
> Example :
>
> ```
> const choices = [ 
> { id: '1', name: 'Programming' }, 
> { id: '2', name: 'Lifestyle' },
>  { id: '3', name: 'Photography' },
>  ];
>
>  <SelectInput 
>    source="category" 
>    choices={choices} 
>    format={(c) => c.name}
>     parse={(name) => choices.find((c) => c.name === name)} 
> />
> ```

There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72684083/15774176) which explains how to input and create two (or more than two) fields using React-Admin as:

> allows users to select an existing record related
> to the current one (e.g. choosing the author for a post). if that you
> want to create a new record instead. You can do so via the onCreate
> prop, [as explained in the doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AutocompleteInput.html#creating-new-choices):
>
> ```
> import { AutocompleteInput, Create, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'react-admin';
> const PostCreate = () => {
>    const categories = [
>        { name: 'Tech', id: 'tech' },
>        { name: 'Lifestyle', id: 'lifestyle' },
> ]; return ( 
> <Create> 
>   <SimpleForm> 
>      <TextInput source="title" /> 
>         <AutocompleteInput 
>               onCreate={(filter) => { 
>                                              const newCategoryName = window.prompt('Enter a new category', filter); 
>                                              const newCategory = { id: categories.length + 1, name: newCategoryName }; 
>                                              categories.push(newCategory); 
>                                              return newCategory;
>                                          }} 
>                                        source="category" 
>                                       choices={categories}
>                                            />
>                                        </SimpleForm> 
>                                           </Create>
>                                      );
>                                     }
> ```

For more information, you can refer to the Official [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html) which explains about the input components and common input props.

Comment: @Eshaan Gupta Posted an answer, is it helpful?